# VbComponents.Remove doesn't always remove module

Tags: vba, excel

I'm trying to use Chip Pearson's code for overwriting an existing VBA code module with an import from another project.  Original code [here](http://www.cpearson.com/excel/vbe.aspx).

The particular section I'm looking at is:

```
With ToVBProject.VBComponents
    .Remove .Item(ModuleName)
End With
```

But this `VBComponents.Remove` call will sometimes only actually take effect once VBA execution has stopped--that is, the delete operation doesn't take effect until all statements are finished, or if the code hits a breakpoint and then I stop debugging.  This is a problem because of the following code for either importing a new module or replacing the existing module's code with the new module:

```
    Set VBComp = Nothing
    Set VBComp = ToVBProject.VBComponents(CompName)

    If VBComp Is Nothing Then
        ToVBProject.VBComponents.import filename:=FName
    Else
        If VBComp.Type = vbext_ct_Document Then
            'delete the module's code,
            'import a temp module,
            'copy over the temp module code,
            'delete the temp module
        End If
    End If
```

The module deletion hasn't taken effect yet, so `VBComp` is not `Nothing`, as far as the debugger knows.  So the `.import` won't be called.

Even if I comment out the `if VBComp.Type = vbext_ct_document then` and `end if` so that the new module's code will overwrite the existing one no matter what `VBComp.Type` it is, the module will still end up getting deleted once the code finishes executing, and no import will happen to replace it.

What's odd is that this doesn't happen with all modules; some actually get deleted in real time after the `VBComponents.Remove` call.

I've seen several different posts about this on various forums, and no satisfactory solution.  For now I'm using a workaround of changing the `.Remove` call to:

```
    With ToVBProject.VBComponents
        .Item(ModuleName).name = ModuleName & "_remove"
        .Remove .Item(ModuleName & "_remove")
    End With
```

so that by changing the name, `ModuleName` appears to no longer exist and therefore the `.import` call will occur.  This assumes, of course, that no module named `ModuleName & "_remove"` actually exists.

Is there a better solution?

Answer (score 11):

I tried the renaming and found that it caused problems with the sheet modules and ThisWorkbook. So I modified it slightly to rename only the non document modules. This seems to work cleanly.

```
        If .Item(ModuleName).Type <> vbext_ct_Document Then
            .Item(ModuleName).Name = ModuleName & "_OLD"
            .Remove .Item(ModuleName & "_OLD")
        Else
            .Remove .Item(ModuleName)
        End If
```

Comment: This is working.  On testing, I find that the "_OLD" modules still remain visible in the project whatever I do, until the code finishes running, and then they automagically disappear.  It *seems* to work fine, the target workbook was saved without those _OLD modules in place.

Comment: An even easier way to do it, instead of renaming, is to just call `Remove` in a **separate procedure** and that does the trick -> https://stackoverflow.com/a/64162635/9150270

Answer (score 3):

It's been quite a while since this question has been asked but I think I came up with something which has not been mentioned before.

Since the modules will not be deleted until the procedure ends, a possible solution is to actually let the procedure end and then call the import procedure via `Application.onTime`.

So, for example

```
Private Sub ImportModules()
  With ThisWorkbook.VBProject.VBComponents
    .Remove .Item(ModuleName)
    Application.onTime Now + TimeValue("00:00:01"), tmpImportModules
  End With
End Sub

Public Sub tmpImportModules()
  With ThisWorkbook.VBProject.VBComponents
    .Import filename:=FName
  End With
End Sub
```

Comment: Thanks for the example

Answer (score 2):

If you have code and method references in the `ThisWorkbook` sheet then Excel might hang on to modules and not delete them. The trick is to hide calls from Excel using `Application.run("foo")` instead of direct calls like `foo()`.
This worked for me in Excel 2010

Answer (score 2):

I've spent endless time on removing/replacing Code Modules in order to find out what triggers works versus doesn't work.

**Removing/replacing Code Modules in another Workbook**

This is by far the least troubling approach and that's why I've implemented it with [Code Module Management](http://www.excelforum.com/development-testing-forum/1112547-multiple-code-module-management-export-import-cleanup-etc.html?highlight=#post4235721). Therein, for any yet not open Workbook, enabled to be selected in a file dialog, the Workbook is opend with:

```
Application.EnableEvents = False
....Open "workbook-fullname" ' selected in a file dialog
Application.EnableEvents = False
```

[Code Module Management](http://www.excelforum.com/development-testing-forum/1112547-multiple-code-module-management-export-import-cleanup-etc.html?highlight=#post4235721) will not work when the target Workbook had been opened manually before (and thus is presented for selection as list of open Workbooks) by not having prevented any VBA-Code from being executed (see [here](http://www.jkp-ads.com/articles/preventopenevent.asp) for ways this can be achieved). Of course this is only an issue when Workbook_Open executes code.

My conclusion: Once Macros(Subprocedures, Functions, etc.) had been executed, a copy of the VBA-Code resides in memory. Thus, any **Remove** will not happen before the procedure which removed the Code Module has finished. Consequently an **Import** considers the Code Module still existing and imports a Code Module with the same name with a numeric suffix to make its name unique. And this of cource is always the case when ...

**Removing/replacing Code Modules in 'ThisWorkbook'** *)

Up to now I have not found any way to achieve this - except for a Class Module not declared in any of the other Code Modules, which I've realized accidentially! . Consequently I tried to temporarily comment out all declarations before **Remove**. Full success! **Remove** and **Import** worked fine. But when I finally tried to un-comment the previously out-commented declaration code lines, Excel allways crashed (in both cases, *.DeleteLines* and *.InsertLines* and *.ReplaceLine*). Since I have not found a solution for this I've given up trying - at least for the time being.

See the [Code Module Management](http://www.excelforum.com/development-testing-forum/1112547-multiple-code-module-management-export-import-cleanup-etc.html?highlight=#post4235721)  for making Cleanup, Remove, Transfer, Export, Import, and even Synchronize much less cumbersome, save and reliable. Even selecting the wrong 'target' Workbook for a transfer or a remove is no drama because of an Undo feature.

*) The difference between *ActiveWorkbook* and *ThisWorkbook* matters here. *ThisWorkbook* is the Workbook in which the VBA code is executed while the *ActiveWorkbook* may be another one. Because normally both are identicall, not paying attention on the difference doesn't matter.

Answer (score 2):

I had the same issue with PowerPoint, but I guess the solution could apply to any Microsoft Office application implementing VBA.

I stopped having issues after I did `Remove` in a separate procedure:

```
Public Sub RemoveVBComponent(ioVBComponents As VBComponents, ioVBComponent As VBComponent)
    Call ioVBComponents.Remove(ioVBComponent)
End Sub
```

that I called this way:

```
With ToVBProject
    Call RemoveVBComponent(.VBComponents,.VBComponents.Item(ModuleName))
End With
```

Answer (score 1):

I have ran into things like this before. The 'DoEvents' command often helps. Have you given that a shot?

Other times, I have placed the command in a do while loop and used a boolean to continually check if the command in question has succeeded. Including the DoEvents command in the loop is sometimes needed.

Just remember to put something in the loop so that after so many cycles it will give up. Getting stuck in an infinite loop can be pesky.

Comment: I'm late to this party, but the DoEvents does the trick for me ...

Answer (score 1):

I have struggled with this problem for many months and have finally found a solution thanks to Rob Bovey (http://www.apps-pro.com/).

The trick is to use the `Application.OnTime` function to call a second procedure with the code you want to run after deleting the code modules.

```
Application.OnTime Now(), "Your_Procedure_Part2"
```

This seems to mimic the VBA code stopping and restarting.  Any code after this line in the calling procedure will not be run.

Answer (score 0):

As Chip Pearson stated, the only way to manage components in a Workbook without conflict  is to use code from within another Workbook. I have put everything I need into a CompMan.xlam Workbook which I use as Add-In. It allows me to export all modules from a Workbook whenever it is saved by the simple code lines:

```
Private Sub Workbook_BeforeSave(ByVal SaveAsUI As Boolean, Cancel As Boolean)
#If DevTest Then
   mCompMan.ExportAll ThisWorkbook
#End If
End Sub
```

By this I never again loose any VBA work and moreover any module is available for import into any other Workbook. I should add that I keep Workbooks with Macros in dedicated folders - at least for code work.

Answer (score -1):

I have had a same issue. In my case, .remove not works when procedures in modules are running.

So I made an update module which is independent from other vb components.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).