# Importing .bas module changes the name of the module

Tags: excel, vba, import, module

The code below replaces modules in a target workbook.

The code searches the Updates subfolder of the current directory for .bas files and, when finding one, removes the old version and then imports the code.

At times one or more of the replaced modules assumes the name xxxxx1 where xxxxx is the name of the .bas file.  It is appending the module name with a "1".  There are no other modules with the same name.  I have checked the .bas file and the first line properly defines the VB_Name - Attribute VB_Name = "xxxxx".  The Remove works.  It is the Import that sometimes results in the issue.

I added an Application.Wait after the Remove but the problem continues.

Note that other functions are used by the routine to determine the directory path and find the files.  Debugging has proven they work.

```
Dim iFilesNum As Integer
Dim iCount As Integer
Dim recMyFiles() As FoundFileInfo
Dim blFilesFound As Boolean
Dim directoryPath As String
Dim wbTarget As Workbook
Dim vbMod As Object
Dim myFile As String
Dim txtLine As String

Set wbTarget = ActiveWorkbook

directoryPath = getDirectoryPath("Updates")
If Dir(directoryPath, vbDirectory) = "" Then
    varX = MsgBox("Updates directory not found.  To apply updates you must first " & _
        "unload the updates from the file that was emailed to you.", vbOKOnly, "IPM by Merlin")
    Exit Sub
End If

blFilesFound = FindFiles(directoryPath, recMyFiles, iFilesNum, "*.bas", False)
If blFilesFound Then
    For iCount = 1 To iFilesNum
        With recMyFiles(iCount)
            .sName = Replace(.sName, ".bas", "")
            Set vbMod = Application.VBE.ActiveVBProject.vbComponents   'First we need to remove the existing module
            vbMod.Remove VBComponent:=vbMod.Item(.sName)
            Application.Wait (Now + #12:00:01 AM#)
            wbTarget.VBProject.vbComponents.Import directoryPath & "\" & .sName & ".bas"   'import the new module.
        End If
        Kill directoryPath & "\" & .sName & ".bas"
        End With
    Next

Else
    varX = MsgBox("No updates files found in the Updates directory.", vbInformation, "IPM by Merlin")

End If
```

Comment: My guess would be that the Office file containing the VBA might be slightly damaged - that it's retaining the name of a module that's been deleted and thus appending 1 to the module name.

Comment: Thanks Cindy for your quick reply!  As info, I am running the current version of Office 365 Excel 2016. If the Office file (.xlsm) is slightly damaged, how might I correct the issue?

Answer (score 0):

The problem seems to be that a module is not always immediately removed. In that case, the 1 is added. I have not found out what exactly is going on: I had a module in file "exporter.bas" and name "exporter", which had this problem. I made a copy to file "yippee.bas" and name "yippee" ( the file contents was the same for the rest, so no 'damaged file') and that had not this problem.

I found [VbComponents.Remove doesn't always remove module](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19800184/vbcomponents-remove-doesnt-always-remove-module]) helpful. I implemented the rename-workaround of the poster of that question.