# Runtime error 32813 - Method 'Name' of object '_VBComponent' failed

Tags: excel, vba

I am trying to rename a module which leads to the run time error. In the below code, 'vbComp.name = moduleName', this line is causing the run time error.
When I looked on it more, I found that the same module already exists and because of that it not allowing it to rename.
Even though I called Remove reference, it is actually not removing the reference.. I tried Doevents, I called the remove reference code in a separate procedure as I shown below.. Still after executing the code, the module is not removed.

Some additional information. So basically this code is being called in 'a.xla' and the XLAName being passed is a different xla 'b.xla'

```
Private Sub AddFileToAddIn(XLAName As String, moduleName As String, Filename As String)
    Dim vbc As VBComponent
    Dim ActiveProjName As String
    ActiveProjName = Application.VBE.ActiveVBProject.name
    Dim vbproj As VBProject
    Dim vbComp As VBComponent
    ' Find the project named XLAName
    For Each vbproj In Application.VBE.VBProjects
        If vbproj.name = XLAName Then
            ' Add the file named FileName
            Set vbComp = vbproj.VBComponents.Import(Filename)
            If Not vbComp Is Nothing Then ' If we have successfully imported the file
                ' See if a module with the name - ModuleName - already exists in this project, and if so, delete it                    
                RemoveModuleFromAddin vbproj, moduleName  '-----> **Not deleting the moduleName**
                ' Change the new modules name to ModuleName from "module1"
                vbComp.name = moduleName '---->**Since the moduleName is not deleted and it exists, renaming it is causing the run time error.**
            End If
            Exit Sub
        End If
    Next vbproj
End Sub

Private Sub RemoveModuleFromAddin(proj As VBProject, moduleName As String)
    Dim module As VBComponent
    For Each module In proj.VBComponents
        If module.name = moduleName Then
            proj.VBComponents.Remove module
            Exit Sub
        End If
    Next module
End Sub
```

Comment: Does the line `proj.VBComponents.Remove module` actually run?

Comment: Yes it will run.

Comment: `RemoveModuleFromAddin` works for me.

Answer (score 0):

When I tested `RemoveModuleFromAddin` it worked fine for me.

This also worked:

```vb
Sub Tester()

    AddFileToAddIn "VBAProject1", "Module3", "C:\Temp\Module3.bas"

End Sub


Private Sub AddFileToAddIn(XLAName As String, moduleName As String, Filename As String)
    
    Dim vbproj As VBProject
    
    On Error Resume Next 'ignore error if no matching project
    Set vbproj = Application.VBE.VBProjects(XLAName)
    On Error GoTo 0
    
    If vbproj Is Nothing Then Exit Sub
    
    On Error Resume Next 'ignore error if no module with matching name
    vbproj.VBComponents.Remove vbproj.VBComponents(moduleName)
    On Error GoTo 0
    
    vbproj.VBComponents.Import(Filename).Name = moduleName
    
End Sub
```

Comment: But it's not working in my case. Is there any chance that 'proj.VBComponents.Remove' will behave differently? I have seen lot of post where they say it doesn't work. But there is no final conclusion on how to fix the issue.

Comment: Sorry - I can only say it worked for me to replace a module in another project.  I saw a few different approaches here - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19800184/vbcomponents-remove-doesnt-always-remove-module  which included using a different method for the module removal (as you did), DoEvents, etc.  You could also try renaming the existing module to a new (unique) name before importing and renaming your new module, then delete it at the end of your process.